# Could not load file or assembly 'log4net,or one of its dependencies.

Tags: dll, dependencies, log4net, graylog

I installed Easygelf.log4net package for log4net version 1.2.0.13 but I am getting error

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.13.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I tried adding the below to the web.config but no luck

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.13.0" newVersion="1.2.13.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Did the package install log4net as a dependency, and if so what version? What version (if any) is specified within the .csproj file?

Comment: i just updated the package log4net to latest version from package manager console   "update-package log4net "

Answer (score 2):

Check assembly version that is referenced in the project and change old version and new version accordingly.
I was also getting same error, and my project was using 1.2.15.0 . so I changed assembly mapping information-

Comment: I also changed the assembly mapping. This helped me: https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/how-to-fix-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-log4net-version-1-2-10-0-119b0715d796